# Sorting a file path tree like Finder's Sort-by-Kind

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to flatten a tree of file paths alphabetically, in a depth-first fashion. It should put shallower paths first, and sort alphabetically within individual directories.

The result that I'd like should look like this:

```
/a.data
/b.data
/x.data
/a/a/e.data
/a/a/f.data
/a/b/c/d.data
/a/c/d.data  
/b/x.data
```

essentially:

```
file vs file - sort alphabetically
file vs directory - file first
directory vs directory - shallow first, otherwise alphabetically
```

before I spend too much time messing with this myself & potentially making errors - is there a Cocoa API which does that? Or maybe just a standard algorithm which does exactly that?

I'm currently doing something like this:

```
// flatList is an unsorted array containing dictionaries
// which have file paths in the kBulkFilepathKey key.
// flatList has been populated earlier by enumerating a list of 
// files and directories, and recursing on the directories.

[flatList sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id  _Nonnull obj1, id  _Nonnull obj2) {

    NSDictionary *d1 = obj1;
    NSDictionary *d2 = obj2;

    // path1, path2 are full paths:
    NSString *path1 = d1[kBulkFilepathKey];
    NSString *path2 = d2[kBulkFilepathKey];

    if(path2.pathComponents.count > path1.pathComponents.count)
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    else if (path1.pathComponents.count > path2.pathComponents.count)
        return NSOrderedDescending;

    return [path1 caseInsensitiveCompare:path2];
}];
```

doesn't really work yet.

thanks!

edit: just realized - I'm looking for the exact same behaviour of OS X Finder, when sorting by `Kind`:

[image: file structure]

but apparently there is no Cocoa API for that - there is [localizedStandardCompare:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/localizedStandardCompare:) on NSString, but this is just an alphabetical sort.

Comment: manually recursing on directories, sorting by path-component count and alphabetically. haven't spent too much time on this, thought I'd better ask before I do an error-prone implementation myself..

Comment: It's better to try before you ask on here, show that you have made some attempt at trying to solve your own problem. Which unfortunately your question doesn't show.

Comment: posted current incomplete code

Answer (score 0):

Once you've determined that the two paths have the same number of components you just need to pair wise compare the components in the two paths - you have a multi-key sort. If a pair of components differ you have the overall answer, just as you have for the components counts. If a pair is equal you move onto the next pair. A simple loop will do it.

HTH